# How messaging actually works in Facebook for freshmen?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

> ***A kinda disclaimer:*** My facebook account got [hacked](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/11014/37472), sends spam messages and so, I had to delete my previous account and recreate another one. My browser has the whole history like, with whom I've chatted, whose pages or profiles I had visited, etc. (which is easy for me)

I tried to give a request to my *girl*. And, I wanna contact her now. When I tried to message her, it showed something like this - like I want to pay something to prove that I'm not a spammer (which I assume happens to every fresher to facebook)...

[image]

But when I used her user ID (*the user ID I've cleared above*) next to the message box URL, `facebook.com/messages/[user-ID]`, I can actually see the messaging window. I sent her a message (I don't know whether it reaches her or not - assuming she'll see see that tomorrow). It showed me that the conversation started now...

[image]

What I wanted to know is a couple of things...

- If I got that dirty *payment scheme* right, why didn't facebook ask me to pay again?
- If I get it wrong, what does both mean? or How do they differ? (I mean, one says - *Pay 19.41 to send to her inbox*, while the other goes just with an <kbd>Enter</kbd> key which seems ridiculous..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Whether you're new to Facebook or not is irrelevant, earlier, all Facebook messages to a person you're not connected & provided the other person has allowed for all to message, were delivered to the 'Other' folder
- Off late, Facebook allows you to send a message directly to the Inbox, instead of the other folder for a fee. This isn't a 'check-for-spammer-routine' - it's one way Facebook is trying to monetize.
- Sending message via the user's profile delivers to their Other folder, much like how it works when you send a message from your messaging window, provided you haven't paid

Comment: So, *precisely* - my message will go to `Others` and once the person accepts my request, it comes back to the inbox. Right?

Comment: No, it remains in Other folder. Future messages will be delivered to inbox

Comment: Ahh... Thanks. *I shouldn't have had wasted time on capturing and editing those artworks..!* :/

Comment: @Waffle'sCrazyPeanut you didn't waste your time for nothing! I had no idea Facebook takes money to send someone a message to their Inbox! I guess I didn't notice it before as I'm not a hardcore Facebook user, was simply googling how the Facebook messaging application works on the back-end and stumbled upon this. :)